# suid bit script perl

Tags: perl, sudo, chmod, chown, suid

I'm making a perl script to change the brightness.
I must write in the file 'brightness' which is set to read only.
I want to use the SUID bit so I did.

```
$> sudo chown root:root brightness
$> sudo chmod 4755 brightness
$> ls -l brightness
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 698 Apr 15 23:22 brightness
$> ./bightness -20
No open bightness
$> sudo ./brightness -20
Done
```

Why it doesn't work for normal user ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's not just that you've misspelled brightness as bightness in your first example, is it?

Comment: Without knowing `brightness`, noone can tell what `No open bightness` actually means!

Answer (score 1):

SUID does not work on normal perl scripts. You either have to use a wrapper, or use `suidperl`. Also, SUID-scripts enforce the `-T` flag.

> http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=130671

Be aware that running script in SUID mode is unsafe!

> http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=perlsec

Answer (score -1):

It is insane :/
I'm only using native perl..

I can not found suidperl on Archlinux and wrappers look unstable don't they ?

Comment: Please don't write comments or further questions as answers!